# Post to facebook wall using Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

For some reason the following is not working.

I have the publish_stream permission. What could be wrong?

```
    function publishToFacebook($app_id, $app_secret, $fb_id) {
    require_once '../facebook-php-sdk-dafef11/src/facebook.php'; 
            $facebook = new Facebook(array(appId => $app_id,
                    secret => $app_secret,
                    cookie => true));
    if(is_null($facebook)) {
    // some code;
    die('bad');
    }
    else {
    // post to fb
        try {
           $post_id = $facebook->api('/' . $fb_id . '/feed/', 'post', array(
            'message' => 'my message',
            'link' => 'http://example.com',
            'picture'  => 'http://example.com/images/logo.jpg',
            'caption' => 'a caption'
            ));
           return $post_id;
        }
           catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
           echo "Error:" . print_r($e, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: update: I changed to "me" and it orks. But still doesn't work for $fb_id

Comment: also, I am getting error #201 "User not visible"

Comment: Sorry, but given the answer, it's too localized, the issue is one of a mistake in your usage of the API, and not an actual programming problem.  I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but the answer ultimately indicates that the question is somewhat flawed in the first place.

Comment: not true, if you would have used the api then you would understand that this str vs int for the fb id is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the input variables are in the correct format.

The problem was that I was using a number (integer) for $fb_id instead of a string. Even tough the facebook ID is a number, it is saved as a string, and therefore the code was not readable by facebook. Once I changed the input it worked perfectly.